# ESXi installation PXE boot with GRUB on BIOS (not EFI)

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, pxe-boot, grub, grub2

all documents mention syslinux/pxelinux as a way to pxeboot ESXi installation, but I'd like to stay with GRUB 2. How to do that?

I'm able, of course, to load GRUB 2 via network (`i386-pc/core.0` for non-UEFI host) but then I can't figure out what should I put to load `mboot.c32` or if it is possible to boot `b.b00` somehow directly.

Comment: From what I have seen ESX uses mboot format. You United all modules and then boot mboot.c32 to have that execute the real code. iPXE forum has some explanations here, for EFI I think it is mboot2

Comment: EFI boot works for me but I have no idea how to load mboot.c32 from GRUB. What is the link to iPXE forum you mentions please?

Comment: What are the reasons to use GRUB instead of iPXE for network booting?

Comment: Good multiplatform support? It's main boot loader in all Linux distros and thus everybody knows how to use it... "I'd like to stay with GRUB 2" - this is clear message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure GRUB for network boot. The [GRUB Networking documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Network.html) can be viewed on local machine with: `pinfo grub2 --node=Network`

A more advanced alternative to grub for PXE booting is [iPXE](https://ipxe.org/). I find iPXE to be a better replacement for [PXELINUX](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXELINUX). You can [build an iPXE bootable image](https://rom-o-matic.dev/) that suits your needs, or [download a generic one](https://ipxe.org/download). You need just UNDI driver for BIOS and SNP for UEFI. iPXE is very configurable: you can have [menus, authentication](https://github.com/skunkie/ipxe-phpmenu); supports iSCSI, NFS, CIFS, HTTP(S)... And it's possible to [boot ESXi](https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/hlcc2x/booting_esxi_7_with_ipxe/fx0n6uw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) with it.

Comment: You did not reply about GRUB and ESXi at all. A tip for iPXE, why? I'm happy with GRUB2. I've been using GRUB2 on network for ages...

Comment: Well, I did. Please follow the links. Last one is for iPXE but similar is for GRUB.

Comment: "...similar is for GRUB" - have you tried that? GRUB2 does not have 'kernel' command.
    `grub> kernel
    error: ../../grub-core/script/function.c:119:can't find command 'kernel'.`

Comment: Try: `linux (tftp,192.168.1.1)/boot/vmlinuz...  root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=[<server-ip>:]<root-dir>[,<nfs-options>]` then `initrd=(tftp,192.168.1.1)//boot/initrd....`

Comment: Sorry, for your case, try: `linux (tftp,192.168.1.1)/boot/b.b00  ks=nfs://192.168.30.176/srv/nfs/esxi7/ks.cfg`

Comment: What is the current grub configuration? And which version of grub are you using? And what is the configuration for TFP and DHCP servers?

Comment: The whole problem is `mboot.c32` is not a format for `linux*`, `multiboot2*` GRUB2 commands. It's customized *syslinux* module. I think only workaround is to `pxechain` `pxelinux.0` and then use it as VMware states (this of course applies to legacy BIOS and it works for me!). "You can try" - this just confirms you have never seen it working directly from GRUB2.

Comment: I was configuring this kind of stuff 10+ years ago. My memory is not perfect and GRUB changed the syntax since then and industry moved to gPXE that evolved into iPXE.